# Calling Hibernate in background threads in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy

I am trying to create a specific type of background processing setup in a grails application.

- A **fixed size** thread pool **exists only for the duration** of the batch of jobs
- A **single session is maintained by each thread**
- Each job runs in a **separate transaction**

I am trying to start the job as follows:

```
int poolSize = 10
ThreadFactory factory = new MyThreadFactory (Executors.defaultThreadFactory())
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (poolSize, factory)

(1..100).each { i ->
  pool.submit {
    try {
      MyDomainClass.withTransaction {
        doSomeWork(i)
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error "error in job ${i}", e
    }
  }
}
```

**MyThreadFactory** creates threads which have a **hibernate session attached** for the duration of the thread.

```
class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {

  ThreadFactory delegate
  PersistenceContextInterceptor persistenceInterceptor

  MyThreadFactory (ThreadFactory delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = ApplicationHolder.getApplication().getMainContext()
    persistenceInterceptor = applicationContext.getBean("persistenceInterceptor");
  }

  Thread newThread (Runnable work) {
    return delegate.newThread {
      persistenceInterceptor.init()
      try {
        work.run()
      } finally {
        persistenceInterceptor.flush()
        persistenceInterceptor.destroy()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to work, however I will get the following error the first time I run the batch job. (Subsequent jobs run without incident)

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static MyDomainClass.save() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[flush:false]]
Possible solutions: save(), save(java.util.Map), save(java.lang.Boolean), wait(), any(), wait(long)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at ...
```

I have tried replacing the persitanceInterceptor with **MyDomainClass.withNewSession {}**, with no effect.

It appears as though GORM methods are not being injected into my domain classes.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, and why running the batch job again allows it to succeed?

**@fixitagain** For completeness the work takes this form:

```
 doSomeWork = { id ->
    MyDomainClass a = MyDomainClass.findById (id)
    a.value = lotsOfWork()
    a.save()
 }
```

I believe the missing save is a red herring, as I tried wrapping the operating in a transaction, and then get an error saying 'DomainClass.withTransaction(Closure)' is not defined.

It looks like there might be a race condition where the first job fails to run, but all following jobs run successfully after (**something?**) has finished starting up.

Comment: At what point int he Grails lifecycle are you starting your jobs? It sounds like it's occurring before the domains have been decorated with their dynamic methods etc.

Comment: The jobs are being triggered from a controller action (for now), so it's well after the domains have been decorated. I should note that if I call all the jobs from the main thread, no problem occurs.

Comment: well, for me GORM is "attached" since it is proposing save(Map) as a possible solution. Can you put the line where you are using save. BTW flush is false by default, meaning it will flush at the end of Hibernate session...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to create your own thread, it might be advisable to use the executor plugin for Grails. It injects the necessary hibernate session to the threads you create, also it is configurable with respect to the executor it uses, number of threads etc. I use it in production with quartz jobs and other scenarios and it works just fine.

[Grails Executor Plugin](http://web.archive.org/web/20191102121657/http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/uberall/grails-executor)
If you have reservations in using it, you can take a look at its code before you write your own threading strategy.

Comment: I've taken a look at the executor plugin, it also uses the persistenceInterceptor to create a session in new threads. At the moment I'm probably more interested in making sure I completely understand how grails/hibernate works before using a plugin. But thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: After a second look at the executor plugin, it will always create a new session per job. Which makes sense in general, but not for the specific task I'm after. I am trying to use the exact same mechanism to create session as the plugin though.

Answer (score 0):

I can't make out from the code or the naming convention, but are you sure you are calling save on an instance of the domain class?

Comment: I assumed that was a 'quirk' with the error message, I'm defiantly calling save() on a domain class instance. Also, I figure if that was the problem it would not explain why the job would finish successfully when I run it a second time.

Comment: before calling a.save(), does a = a.merge() help?

Answer (score 0):

The missing method exception implies that you're calling save on the Class, not the instance.

edit: GORM has already applied the additional methods, as you can see in the suggested solution method names.